# access images from assets in css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My bootstrap layout was doing the following:

```
body {
...
 background-image:url('../img/bg.png');
}
```

now this worked fine. However, when integrating with rails, the image isn't showing up, the path is still correct:

```
assets > stylesheets > docs.css (has the line mentioned above)
assets > img > bg.png
```

however, its not working, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

body {
...
 background-image:url('bg.png');
}

Comment: This is because of asset pipeline, enter  Rails.application.config.assets.paths in your rails console